# Cannot use text, ntext, or image columns in the 'inserted' and 'deleted' tables

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I got an error "Cannot use text, ntext, or image columns in the 'inserted' and 'deleted' tables", since there are ntext fields in original table, I had attached a trigger to.

Here is a solution: http://lazycodeprogrammer.blogspot.com/2009/08/how-to-use-inserteddeleted-with.html

But original (non modified) query is complex enough. What should I write instead of SELECT * FROM INSERTED, using JOIN operator, as it's recommended?

Comment: What is it you want to do? Can you show us your trigger (at least the most relevant parts of it)? Your question isn't very clear....

Comment: I'm trying to get inserted rows within my trigger. If I execute "SELECT * FROM INSERTED" query, I get "Cannot use text, ntext, or image columns in the 'inserted' and 'deleted' tables" error. I know why: because original table contains ntext field.

How should I modify my query to workaround this?

Comment: @noober, without you showing any SQL, all anyone can say is to just implement what you have posted yourself in your link.

Comment: All SQL is presented in the article. [UPDATE t SET t.newtext = i.text FROM tbl_Dest t, INSERTED i, DELETED d WHERE t.PK_ID = i.PK_ID] modified to [UPDATE t SET t.newtext = s.text FROM tbl_Dest t, tbl_Source s JOIN INSERTED i ON s.PK_ID = i.PK_ID, DELETED d WHERE t.PK_ID = s.PK_ID]. I just wanted to understand, what the trick is about.

Comment: See also this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9101924/sql-trigger-cannot-do-instead-of-delete-but-is-required-for-ntext-image-columns

Comment: The article you linked to is useful for handling Inserts (and only if you will be inserting one row at a time and have a Primary key on the table).  Otherwise it won't work because you are joining the DELETED table to the source table that no longer has the record in it.  As Paulo suggests below, the only way to do this is to use "Instead Of" triggers if you are not able to change the DataType to VarChar(Max) - Which is a real-world scenario when working against a 3rd-party database.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A nice solution has been found:

1. SELECT FROM INSERTED just id column (it's not ntext or image and query is being executed).
2. SELECT from original table * with the same ids.
3. If required, use UPDATED() on INSERTED to be aware, what columns have been changed.

Comment: This is actually not so nice solution. While it works OK with inserted table, with deleted table this approach is wrong since you will receive values after update, not before update.

Answer (score 24):

The real problem is you are trying to select columns in your inserted table that are of type ntext, text or image. This is not allowed in a trigger.

The real solution would be to change all your ntext, to nvarchar(max), text to varchar(max) and image to varbinary(max) as suggested by MS.

MS states that those types are deprecated and will be removed in future version.

Also, ntext are really slow as performance since there are no in-row data.

Comment: LOL. Well, the realest problem then is MS tell us "those types are deprecated and will be removed in future version, bla-bla-bla", but they USE them on their own. Guess where? In SharePoint DB. And I have to know, what rows are changed and what fields are changed in spite of NTEXTs are widely and actively used for storing lists. I know, what you will say: "Don't use DB directly, use OM instead". Please, don't. I was exploring the crappy OM the whole last year during several projects, perfomance and feature set I want are only available on the DB level.

Answer (score 1):

Using "INSTEAD OF " triggers may solve the problem because the text, ntext and image fields are available in the "inserted" and "deleted" tables.
Look at http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=148387 to see how it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following trigger after insert on `yourtable`:

```
SELECT textfields
FROM yourtable
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM {inserted/deleted}
  WHERE {inserted/deleted}.PK = {yourtable}.PK
)
```

Answer (score 0):

With this join, you will have access to all the fields you need in the trigger from the main table and you will not have any restrictions.

```
CREATE OR ALTER     TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_Insert]
       ON  [dbo].[T_Your_Table]
           AFTER INSERT
       AS 
BEGIN 
     insert into 
     T_Your_Log_Table
            (field1,field2)
    select 
            I.field1
           ,Y.field2 -- type text 
           
    FROM 
            Inserted I join
            T_Your_Table Y on I.Primary_Filed = Y.Primary_Filed
```