# SQL Server after update trigger ERROR with TEXT Column

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to create an after update trigger using SQL Server, and save the modified and new values in a log table. But I'm getting this error:

> Cannot use text, ntext, or image columns in the 'inserted' and
>   'deleted' tables.

This is my trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgIssuedFormProperties
ON IssuedFormProperties 
AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO ProposalsRevision(IssuedFormID, NewPropertyValue, OldPropertyValue, PropertyName)
        SELECT 
            i.IssuedFormID, d.PropertyValue, 
            i.PropertyValue, i.PropertyName
        FROM 
            Inserted i
        INNER JOIN 
            Deleted d ON i.IssuedFormID = d.IssuedFormID 
                      AND i.PropertyName = d.PropertyName
END
```

This is the structure of my tables

```
[ProposalsRevision]
(
    [IssuedFormID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PropertyName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [OldPropertyValue] [text] NOT NULL,
    [NewPropertyValue] [text] NOT NULL,
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
)

[IssuedFormProperties]
(
    [UnitID] [varchar](8) NOT NULL,
    [IssuedFormID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PropertyName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [PropertyValue] [text] NULL
)
```

Comment: Probably a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3178312/cannot-use-text-ntext-or-image-columns-in-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables

Comment: You should not use the text datatype. It has been deprecated for more than a decade now. Change to varchar(max)...do you really need that much data? The varchar datatype can hold up to 8,000 characters which is a LOT of information.

Comment: Changing column data type to Varchar(MAX), worked fine.